# Connect to LAN resource via ssh tunnel

Tags: networking, ssh, ssh-tunneling

I have the following problem. From machine `A` I connect to machine `B` over the internet via ssh and port forwarding. Machine `B` is part of my local network and has connection to machine `C` which acts as a server inside the `LAN`.

```
A --------- | ---- B ---- C
  INTERNET GW        LAN
```

Now I want to start a program on `A` that needs access to `C` without using a vpn connection. I tried ssh tunneling:

```
#user@A: ssh -N user@B -L 9999:B:9999
```

But when I start the program on `A` it cant connect to `C`. I guess it has something to do with `A` not having a route to `C` because it has only a local address (192.168.something) . How can I find out whats going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need.

```
#user@A: ssh -N user@B -L 9999:C:9999
```

When you connect from A with telnet

```
#user@A: telnet localhost 9999
```

Comment: Still i get a `No route to host` error when i try to  `telnet C 9999`

Comment: Updated with telnet command

Comment: @greole of course. From A you should `telnet A 9999` or `localhost 9999`